# Bathroom electric issue

Tags: electrical, bathroom

Good afternoon,
First time here so I sincerely appreciate any help..
House background, built in 1907. Only electrical ever permitted was in late 70s. All else added etc done by previous owner was all done without permits. Mainly an illegal 45 foot trailer he had in backyard. I've cleaned some up but this is above me as I'm still learning electrical and while I'm getting there, and since affording an electrician is out, I bend to you...

Ok, by the pics, the double switch is what I want in the box with the gfi outlet. Gfi is as you see wired separate. The regular wall switch you see is outside the bathroom on my outside wall. Basically a 3 foot run. No idea what that outlet is fed off of but do know it in fact supplies the bathroom lighting. Originally, (I should have photographed) there was a single pole switch there beside the gfi outlet. If you can see the wiring ok, the hot from that outlet in the hallway was middle stripped and wrapped around the top common screw then either run directly to other common terminal and other wires nutted together or it was nutted with one light and other light was run into other common screw. Whew,
My goal is to have this double switch control 2 lights. One on wall (loose wires) and one to new fan light combo which I've already installed and wired to switch on together. When I hooked this all up first time, the top switch turns fan on, the other switch simply turned off that hall outlet. Power to the wires for light above mirror but not sure if its right till my light is delivered. But seems to have constant power regardless. What are my options here?
Thanks again [[image: bathroom gangbox][1]]
[![hallway outlet[image: new switchnew fan combo]
[image: vanity light]

Comment: Good to post pictures, but it's not really clear what's going on from the pictures (which might be because you forgot to take pictures before you took it apart..)

Comment: More discussion, info and pix [here](https://www.diychatroom.com/f18/double-light-switch-problem-700523/).

Answer (score 1):

You have hot and switched mixed up (or hot feed and hot out) if you have constant power where you want switched, and switching the switch turns off the outlet in the hallway.

*i.e.* you THINK the outlet in the hallway powers the lights, when it appears that the lights power the outlet in the hallway. So the lights come first, then the hot (used to) run on to the hallway, and now the wire to the hallway is passing through a switch, so the hallway is switched, and the thing you want switched has constant power.

Comment: Ok starting to follow now. See know just enough to torch my own house. I'll take better pics and post better so maybe I can  be understood better. Please bear with me..

Comment: Don't beat yourself up, but do try to think it through. The only way (far too common) that you turn off your supply by flipping the switch is to blow a fuse or trip a breaker. So, that can't be the supply, after all if it's switched now.